# Take care of me, I can give death, but without me life stops

Tags: riddle, word

**Disclaimer** : This is my first riddle, so be nice please! Also, don't forget to give your opinion.

```
I am common, but very rare in some places,
I can be a huge place or a single drop.
Take care of me, I can give death,
but without me life stops.
```

**What this riddle is talking about?**

Comment: Nice Riddle but i have the Feeling i heard it before. If you thought of it by yourself... Godd Job.. But very easy

Comment: I'm newish here myself - about a week (current date 11 Aug 2015). It's really hard to make a balance between obvious, impossible and ambiguous.  I would say that to experienced riddlers such as you will find here, yours tends towards the obvious end of the spectrum. However I like your formulation and wish you well - riddling is fun!

Comment: Another thought. The big clue that gives it away is the phrase "a single drop". Most people immediately think of a drop of water.  The problem would come if you replaced that with a less obvious phrase. Then the riddle would become ambiguous and you would get many plausible answers that didn't necessarily include the one you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for the tips guys, I'll try to make a harder one soon :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Water

I am common, but very rare in some places

> Some places like the Great Lakes in the US have plenty of water, while the Sahara Desert is lacking.

I can be a huge place or a single drop

> You can have an ocean or a drop of water

Take care of me, I can give death

> You can drown

but without me life stops

> All life on Earth requires water

Comment: Wow. That was very fast. Don't forget to give your opinion about this riddle :)

Comment: Polluted water can also cause death if you drink it.